# The use of <pre> for formatting code hides <> symbols

Tags: support, code-formatting

I was posting a code that used `If <> Condition`, however when I tried to use the <kbd>{}</kbd> to Format the code after an Item List  `-`. It just didn't work, as can be seen below:

- sdad

  fdsfds
  fdsfs
  dsfsd

So I tried using `<pre><code>`, however, the <> would disappear. As can be seen on some examples:

Using <kbd>{}</kbd>:
 `Different <> Diff`

Using ``

`Different <> Diff`

Using `<pre><code>`

```
Different
```

Using `<pre>`

```
Different
```

Using `<code>`

`Different <>`

Why does it happen and is there a way to fix it? Or to get around?

Comment: I fail to see what's wrong with any of the code formatting options that you've shown.  `<pre>` isn't for code formatting, and so understandably doesn't properly format code.

Comment: It is for preformatted text, however i didn't know them. Googling i found a thread that said to use <pre><code>, so i went to read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code, it seems confusing if you don't know what is a preformatting. Because people will try to use them both together. At least i did.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you indent the code by *eight* spaces, it works:

- sdad

  ```
  fdsfds
  fdsfs
  dsfsd
  ```

If for some reason a `<` doesn't display, you can use `&lt;` instead, e.g.

```
<pre>&lt;test></pre>
```

becomes:

```
<test>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `{}` code formatting tool, it indents your code by four spaces. This indentation is then converted by the Markdown parser into a `<pre><code>` block with all the special characters inside suitably escaped.

However, when the indented code appears after a list item, the four spaces acts instead as a continuation of the list item.

If you want the code block to appear *inside* the list item, you have to indent it using **8** spaces. (Note that it is not possible to start a list item with a code block; You need to put some text in first.)

If instead you want it to appear *after* the list, you can break them up with an HTML comment (`<!-- -->`) or a language hint to trigger the correct syntax colouring if appropriate (`<!-- language: lang-css -->`).

Most languages are rendered correctly without hints, but CSS in particular is rendered badly by the default parser.

---

If you don't want to use the Markdown features and instead want to write your own HTML, then you need to escape all special characters (eg. `<` and `&`) yourself. For example:

```
<pre><code>Different &lt;> Diff</code></pre>
```

will be rendered as:

```
Different <> Diff
```

---

You can learn more about Markdown at: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to indenting code after a list item by 8 spaces, use an HTML comment or `<anyinvalidtag>` to end the list before the code block:

- sdad

```
fdsfds fdsfs dsfsd
```

Source:

```
- sdad

<something>

    fdsfds fdsfs dsfsd
```